# PHP passthru() blocks with process replacement

Tags: php, bash, daemon, io-redirection

I have a problem with PHP `passthru()` blocking when it is supposed to start a daemon.

I have a Node.js daemon with a bash script wrapper around it. That bash script uses a bit of process replacement because the Node.js server can't directly log to syslog. The bash script contains a command like this:

```
forever -l app.log app.js
```

But because I want it to log to syslog, I use:

```
forever -l >(logger) app.js
```

The `logger` process replacement created a file descriptor like `/dev/fd/63` whose path is passed to the `forever` command as the logfile to use.

This works great when I start the daemon using the bash script directly, but when the bash script is executed using PHP passthru() or exec() then these calls will block. If I use a regular logfile instead of the process replacement then both passthru() and exec() work just fine, starting the daemon in the background.

I have created a complete working example (using a simple PHP daemon instead of Node.js) on Github's Gist: https://gist.github.com/1977896 (needs PHP 5.3.6+)

Why does the `passthru()` call block on the process replacement? And is there anything I can do to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

passthru() will block in PHP even if you start a daemon, it's unfortunate. I've heard some people have luck rewriting it with nohup:

```
exec('/path/to/cmd');
```

then becomes:

```
exec('nohup /path/to/cmd &');
```

Personally, what I've had the most luck with is exec()'ing a wget exec to call another script (or the same script) to actually run the blocking exec. This frees the calling process from getting blocked by giving it to another http process not associated with the live user. With the appropriate flags, wget will return immediately, not waiting for a response:

```
exec('wget --quiet --tries=1 -O - --timeout=1 --no-cache http://localhost/path/to/cmd');
```

The http handler will eventually time out which is fine and should leave the daemon running. If you need output (hence the passthru() call you're making) just run the script redirecting output to a file and then poll that file for changes in your live process.